# Use bluetooth on Ubuntu 20.04 Virtual Box guest (host is also 20.04)

Tags: virtualbox, bluetooth, 20.04

In my host - Ubuntu 20.04 I do have bluetooth in settings.

On the Virtual Box guest however in Settings → Bluetooth it says `No Bluetooth found`

how to connect bluetooth to the guest?

Answer (score 0):

Form "Machine" menu select "USB" and click the bluetooth device. It should appear in the guest machine, but disappear in the host one.

Comment: It does not appear in my guest Windows.

Comment: Under Machine I do not see USB. I see it however under Devices. Unfortunately there are no USB devices :/ I already installed USB 3 plug-in and selected USB 3 since it is a USB 3 port